# Excessive dirty memory

Tags: ios, image, memory-management, swiftui, pencilkit

I'm developing an iOS app for drawing on a simple canvas.
The app manages one canvas per time (layers are managed differently).
I didn't use 3rd party libraries and all components are Apple friendly (canvas is PencilKit for example) while the UI is all SwiftUI.
The app never crashed but while testers are playing on it, the dirty memory grows and the app is noticeably slower.

The Instruments record shows a grew in correct memory when the app starts, but the memory used never decreases, even when the action using memory is finished. This causes a constant increase in dirty memory.

I'm working on simulator and testers on real devices like iPad 12.9 4th generation.

I heavily work with Dispatchers, UIImages and CIImages.

Attached part of the Instruments VM Tracker of dirty memory.

```
        VM Tracker

          
                                VIRTUAL RESIDENT    DIRTY  SWAPPED VOLATILE   NONVOL    EMPTY   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE     SIZE     SIZE     SIZE     SIZE     SIZE     SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     ======= ========    =====  ======= ========   ======    =====  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K      40K      40K       0K       0K      40K       0K        1 
CG raster data                    46.3M    46.2M    46.2M     140K       0K       0K       0K       21 
CoreAnimation                     93.5M    92.5M    92.5M    1036K       0K     108K       0K       37 
CoreData                             8K       8K       8K       0K       0K       0K       0K        1 
CoreData Object IDs               4100K       4K       4K       0K       0K       0K       0K        2 
CoreImage                        114.6M   114.6M   114.6M       0K       0K       0K       0K        8 
CoreUI image data                  588K     424K     424K     164K       0K       0K       0K        3 
Foundation                        1040K    1028K    1028K       0K       0K       0K       0K        4 
IOSurface                         28.1M    23.7M    23.7M       0K       0K    23.7M       0K       10 
Image IO                          9952K    5984K    5984K    3968K       0K       0K       0K        4 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K       8K       8K       0K       0K       0K       0K        1 
MALLOC guard page                   32K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K        8 
MALLOC metadata                    220K     160K     160K      20K       0K       0K       0K       11 
MALLOC_LARGE                      7756K    5520K    5520K    2116K       0K       0K       0K       25         see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC_LARGE (empty)              8464K    7676K    7676K     520K       0K       0K       0K       13         see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC_LARGE_REUSABLE             30.3M    27.2M    11.7M       0K       0K       0K       0K       10         see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC_NANO                      128.0M    5756K    5756K    1268K       0K       0K       0K        1         see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC_NANO (empty)              384.0M       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K        1         see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC_SMALL                     112.0M    6728K    6728K     388K       0K       0K       0K       14         see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC_TINY                       24.0M    2772K    2772K       8K       0K       0K       0K       24         see MALLOC ZONE table below
Performance tool data              448K     432K     432K      16K       0K       0K       0K        8         not counted in TOTAL below
SQLite page cache                  512K     508K     508K       4K     508K       0K       0K        8 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K        7 
Stack                             11.0M     400K     364K      44K       0K       0K       0K        7 
Stack (reserved)                   520K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Stack Guard                          4K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K        1 
VM_ALLOCATE                       17.8M    1360K    1360K     148K       0K       0K       0K       44 
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)               4K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                            16.9M    9751K    3025K     664K       0K       0K       0K      397 
__DATA_CONST                      33.9M    29.8M     772K     742K       0K       0K       0K      391 
__DATA_DIRTY                        20K      19K      19K       0K       0K       0K       0K        6 
__FONT_DATA                          4K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       402.5M   176.6M       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K       15 
__OBJC_RO                         54.0M    30.0M       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2592K    1610K      18K       0K       0K       0K       0K        1 
__TEXT                           392.7M   102.7M      28K       0K       0K       0K       0K      407 
__UNICODE                          588K     336K       0K       0K       0K       0K       0K        1 
mapped file                      268.3M    32.2M      24K       0K       0K       0K       0K      221 
shared memory                    233.1M    1532K    1532K   231.6M       0K       4K       0K       23 
unused but dirty shlib __DATA      340K     115K     115K     226K       0K       0K       0K      279 
===========                     ======= ========    =====  ======= ========   ======    =====  ======= 
TOTAL                              2.4G   726.0M   331.5M   242.7M     508K    23.8M       0K     2011 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.4G   726.0M   331.5M   242.7M     508K    23.8M       0K     2011
```

I need to understand why memory is not deallocated when a SwiftUI's view disappears.

This is the simple flow:

```
 start the app         20MB memory
 open canvas         200MB memory
 close canvas        (should be 20MB again) 200 MB
```

So:
is there a way in Instruments to find exactly which Object retains dirty memory?

Thanks